# SqlDataSource oracle 11g ora-01036

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

These days I develop test system for my company using Asp.net.
However, I've never learned about ASP.NET and C# before.

So, I need your help.

this is my problem.
Now, I am using Oracle DB, .NET 4.5 FrameWorks on VS2013, and Oracle.DataAccess dll for db connection.

I connected DB using asp:SqlDataSource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:GCK_DB%>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GCK_DB.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT b.PRODUCT_IDX ,a.VERSION ,a.BUY_DATE ,a.LICENSE_CODE ,a.RESELLER_IDX FROM BUYINFO a, PRODUCTS b, CUSTOMER c WHERE 1=1 AND a.PRODUCT_IDX = b.PRODUCT_IDX AND a.CUS_IDX = c.CUS_IDX AND a.COM_IDX = (Select a.com_idx as com_idx from CUSTOMER a, COMPANY b where 1=1 and a.COM_IDX = b.COM_IDX and a.CUS_IDX = :CUS_IDX)" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE BUYINFO SET PRODUCT_IDX = 1, VERSION = '2014v6', BUY_DATE = SYSDATE, LICENSE_CODE='SE115AC-DJ-810606-06-64U5QFB', CUS_IDX = :CUS_IDX  WHERE LICENSE_CODE = 'SE115AC-DJ-810606-06-64U5QFB'">
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CUS_IDX" QueryStringField="CUS_IDX" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
 </SelectParameters>                    
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CUS_IDX" QueryStringField="CUS_IDX" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
  </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Whenever I run this code, select command works well.
However, UdateCommand do not work, and it occurs ORA-01036 exception.

I do not know why. 
if I remove this code "CUS_IDX = :CUS_IDX" on update query, it works well.
and also, if I change this code "CUS_IDX = :CUS_IDX" to "CUS_IDX = 1" on update query, it works well.

it only occurs whenever I try to use parameter on updatecommand.

I tried to find solution on google but I can not find any answer that I want.

please help me.

ps.
this is DB table info that I use.

```
CREATE TABLE BUYINFO(
  LICENSE_CODE VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,  
  PRODUCT_IDX NUMBER NOT NULL,
  VERSION VARCHAR2(100),  
  BUY_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  RESELLER_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
  COM_IDX     NUMBER,
  CUS_IDX     NUMBER,
  REG_DATE    DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE ,
  REG_IN     NUMBER
);
```

Comment: Please try using @CUS_IDX instead of :CUS_IDX

Comment: I tried to use "@CUS_IDX"  instead of :CUS_IDX.
However, If I use "@CUS_IDX", I occur another exception ora-00936:missing expression.

and I found that "@" tag only uses for MS-SQL, but I am using oracle.
(ㅠ.ㅠ)